# sql server max memory change event viewer log

Tags: windows, sql-server, configuration, memory, database

In the Windows Event Viewer application, I see a record that the maximum memory value of SQL Server is reduced by 99%. After this process, we could not access the database from anywhere.

How can we find concrete evidence of the reason for this data change? Did a person do it, was it a cyberattack, was it an automatic timer, etc...

Event viewer screen shot image;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5dhw.png)

SQL Server Managment Studio Configuration Log screen shot image;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UfjU.png)

Comment: `Did a person do it` yes. A person did it. They opened SSMS, entered the new value, and clicked ok.

Comment: To be precise: they opened SSMS, enabled advanced mode view, entered new values for max and min, clicked OK, then disabled advanced view.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Error Log should provide who did it. Examine the current and the previous log and search for event 2342.

```
message:
Date        3/25/2014 
Log     Windows NT (Application)

Source      MSSQLSERVER
Category        (2)
Event       2342
User        [who_did_it]
Computer    [the_host]

Message
Configuration option 'min server memory (MB)' changed from 2048 to 512. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
```

In addition, examine the Details section of the Event ID 15457 (Windows Event Log), there sometimes you may find a Windows user/login named that made the memory adjustment.